# Expression Tree. Storing LambdaExpression with runtime types in Expression.Variable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to construct an expression tree from a different structure. Let's call that structure S for convenience. I came across a problem. I have to be able to construct a `LambdaExpression` from graph in S and based on input and output types that S specifies. S specifies expression itself and signature of the `LambdaExpression` (eg. `Func<int, int>, Func<bool, string, int>` etc). Since I can use non-generic `Expression.Lambda(...)` when building the expression I can safely ignore the signature. But it doesn't work when the expression has recursive calls. I must store the expression itself beforehand in `Expression.Variable(typeof(Func<...>))` for future calls. But I don't know the types on compile time because I get S as data, it's totally a runtime thing.

Here is the example:

```
public class Structure
{
    public Parameter[] InputParams { get; set; }
    public Parameter OutputParam { get; set; }
    public Graph Expression { get; set; }
}
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
public class Builder
{
    public static Expression Build(Structure s)
    {
        var inputParams = new ParameterExpression[s.InputParams.Length];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var param in s.InputParams)
        {
            inputParams[index++] = Expression.Parameter(Utils.GetDataType(param.Type), param.Name);
        }

        ParameterExpression delegVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(Func<int, int>), "sum"); // here types of Func must be taken from S

        LambdaExpression expression = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Block(
                new[] { delegVar },
                Expression.Assign(delegVar,
                    Expression.Lambda(
                        Expression.Block(
                            // some work is done here
                            Expression.Invoke(delegVar, inputParams)
                        ),
                        inputParams
                    )
                ),
                Expression.Invoke(delegVar, inputParams)
            ),
            inputParams
        );

        return expression;
    }
}
```

Please ignore the fact that expression will throw StackOverflowException on runtime.

Comment: Can you also show an example of how Structure is initialized? So example of how you call that `Build()` method.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I already solved the problem. I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

After extensive search on the internet I was finally able to solve the problem. What I did was I created a type definition and made a generic type out of it by passing type arguments. Here is the solution.

```
public class Structure
{
    public Parameter[] InputParams { get; set; }
    public Parameter OutputParam { get; set; }
    public Graph Expression { get; set; }
}
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
public class Builder
{
    public static Expression Build(Structure s)
    {
        var inputParams = new ParameterExpression[s.InputParams.Length];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var param in s.InputParams)
        {
            inputParams[index++] = Expression.Parameter(GetDataType(param.Type), param.Name);
        }

        Type lambdaDefinition = GetLambdaTypeDefinition(s.InputParams.Length);
        Type[] typeArgs = s.InputParams.Select(p => GetDataType(p.Type)).Concat(new Type[] { GetDataType(s.OutputParam.Type) }).ToArray();
        Type lambdaType = lambdaDefinition.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

        ParameterExpression delegVar = Expression.Variable(lambdaType, "sum");

        LambdaExpression expression = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Block(
                new[] { delegVar },
                Expression.Assign(delegVar,
                    Expression.Lambda(
                        Expression.Block(
                            // some work is done here
                            Expression.Invoke(delegVar, inputParams)
                        ),
                        inputParams
                    )
                ),
                Expression.Invoke(delegVar, inputParams)
            ),
            inputParams
        );

        return expression;
    }

    private static Type GetDataType(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case DataTypes.Boolean:
                return typeof(bool);
            case DataTypes.Number:
                return typeof(double);
            case DataTypes.NumArray:
                return typeof(double[]);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Type GetLambdaTypeDefinition(int inputLength)
    {
        switch (inputLength)
        {
            case 1:
                return typeof(Func<,>);
            case 2:
                return typeof(Func<,,>);
            case 3:
                return typeof(Func<,,,>);
            case 4:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,>);
            case 5:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,>);
            case 6:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,>);
            case 7:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,>);
            case 8:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,>);
            case 9:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,>);
            case 10:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,,>);
            case 11:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,,,>);
            case 12:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,,,,>);
            case 13:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,,,,,>);
            case 14:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>);
            case 15:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>);
            case 16:
                return typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>);
            default:
                throw new Exception("Too many input parameters");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: My solution is bad. As Ivan Stoev mentioned there is a method exactly for that purpose. It's [Expression.GetFuncType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.getfunctype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Really that was your issue? [`Expression.GetFuncType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.getfunctype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Oh, that is much better! Thanks a lot! Silly me, I should have read the documentation first before searching for the answers.